# Does MongoDB's GridFS has minimum file size requirement?

Tags: django, mongodb

Sometimes I generated empty files (size = 0 on Linux) but they are necessary to insert into the MongoDB file storage.

I use Django's `models.FileField`, but I want to rule that out because it was accepted I think (really can't be too sure), and sent off to insert to MongoDB.
Any idea if it has the minimum file size?

Comment: I don't quite understand: Are you trying to make Django ignore empty files (i.e. make it not insert them into the GridFS) or are you worried about empty GridFS files being "invalid" in some way?

Answer (score 1):

There is no minimum file size for GridFS .. this is easy to test with the `mongofiles` command line utility:

```
$ touch foo
$ mongofiles put foo
connected to: 127.0.0.1
added file: { _id: ObjectId('501385ebf51e4d7d24554d5b'), filename: "foo", chunkSize: 262144, uploadDate: new Date(1343456747050), md5: "d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e", length: 0 }
done!
$ mongofiles list
connected to: 127.0.0.1
foo 0
```

Comment: Note: When `put`ting an empty buffer/file, only the document in fs.files is created and nothing will be created in fs.chunks (not even an empty chunk).